# Progress dbtool errors

Tags: sql, linux, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I am trying to run the Progress dbtool on our database but it is not working. I get to the proenv prompt as suggested by the documentation that I have. When I execute the dbtool against our database "access" (that's the name of our progress database)

Here are my steps:

```
[root@server ~]# cd /usr/dlc10.2B/bin
[root@server bin]# ./proenv

      DLC: /usr/dlc10.2B
   WRKDIR: /usr/wrk
      OEM: /usr/oemgmt
OEMWRKDIR: /usr/wrk_oemgmt

Inserting /usr/dlc10.2B/bin to beginning of path and
setting the current directory to /usr/wrk.

OpenEdge Release 10.2B04 as of Thu Mar  3 19:14:26 EST 2011

proenv>dbtool access

/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 2: DLC:: command not found
/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 3: WRKDIR:: command not found
/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 4: OEM:: command not found
/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 5: OEMWRKDIR:: command not found
/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 7: Inserting: command not found
/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 8: setting: command not found
/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 10: OpenEdge: command not found
/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 12:
/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 12: root@server:/usr/wrk
/usr/dlc10.2B/bin/dbtool: line 12: root@server:/usr/wrk: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What shell are you using?

Have you edited proenv?

proenv is a shell script.  The errors that you report are simple shell variable assignments failing -- as if you are executing proenv with something other than "sh".  The first few lines of proenv should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
# proenv

    DLC="/usr/dlc"
    WRKDIR="/usr/wrk"
    OEM="/usr/oemgmt"
    OEMWRKDIR="/usr/wrk_oemgmt"
    PATH=$DLC/bin:$DLC/perl/bin:$PATH
    PS1="proenv>"
   export DLC WRKDIR PATH PS1 OEM OEMWRKDIR OEE OEEWRKDIR

   #cd to the work directory
   cd $WRKDIR
```

For that to fail you are either running a broken shell or someone has messed with the script.

By the way -- you should not need to be root to run dbtool.  And you do not need to have your current directory in /usr/dlc10.2B/bin when you run proenv.

Actually dbtool should run just fine from a plain old command prompt so long as DLC is defined and $DLC/bin is in your PATH.

Comment: I am using putty.exe from my laptop with connection ssh. Our software vendor just upgraded us from 9.1E to 10.2B.

Comment: echo $SHELL
    ls -l $DLC/bin/proenv

Comment: followed by 2) ls -l $DLC/bin/proenv

Comment: The idea  being to figure out what shell you are running and maybe determine if proenv has been meddled with.

Comment: # echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
# ls -l $DLC/bin/proenv
ls: /bin/proenv: No such file or directory

I think that's the problem. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: bash should work just fine as a shell.  The failure of the "ls" command means that DLC isn't defined in your environment.

Comment: Taking another look at your original post -- those error messages are wrong.  "dbtool" is an executable.  Yet you are reporting errors that look very much like shell script errors.  Something isn't right -- maybe you have edited the output?  Or perhaps "dbtool" isn't dbtool -- you may have a corrupted installation.

Comment: The dbtool was trashed... after re-installing it everything was back to normal. Thanks again for helping me troubleshoot this.